# Top Base Fractional Number

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, fractions, computer-vision

For example:

$ 2^3 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot2 $

But what about a fractional power such as:

$$ 2^{2/3} =  ? $$

1) How would I explain this?

2) How would I find value?

3) How would computers calculate this number?

Comment: 1. The first line is not a definition, rather the result of the definition for integers. 2. By plugging in the value of the definition of an exponential function. 3. As far as I know they use power series approximation due to the fact that we know the accuracy of number of decimal places by the number of terms it calculates.

Comment: @MatthewLiu  Can you elaborate question 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question #3: In the past, when computers didn't have the vast amounts of memory they do now, finding a root often fell to such methods as bisection, Newton's method, regula falsi, the secant method, and others.  Plus, you had to write the programs, put them on cards, and be restricted to a few decimal places.  These days, there are programs that will calculate your root to whatever accuracy you wish - I don't know what algorithm they use, but often it's one that reduces the amount of time and the amount of error in finding the root.

Comment: nice answer! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$2\times 2\times 2=2^{3}$$ and $$(2^{3})^{1/3}=2$$ and $$2^{2/3}=\sqrt[3]{4}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{8}{2}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But question 3 has not been answered.

Comment: A computer with a Computer Algebra System calculates this number as i have written.